# SQL select row with max value or distinct value and sum all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data that is returned to me.  I need to get a distinct or max sum of all the commission by taxid for a single repnbr.  The 'qtrlycommrep' column is the value I'm trying to get to, but not able to.  For repnbr c590, I need to get the 854.66 commission amount, which is the max for each taxid.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far. Using the `Row_number`

```
select distinct 
        sub.Repnbr
    ,   (sub.QtrLYComm) as qtrlycommrep
   from ( 
        select distinct repnbr, QtrLYComm
        , rn = row_number() over(partition by repnbr order by QtrLYComm desc)

    from #qtrly
    ) sub
    where sub.rn = 1
```

Cross Apply

```
 select distinct
        #qtrly.repnbr
    ,   x.QtrLYComm as qtrlycommrep

    from #qtrly
        cross apply (
            select top 1
                *
            from #qtrly as i
            where i.repnbr = Repnbr
            order by i.qtrlycomm desc
            ) as x;
```

inner join

```
select
    #qtrly.repnbr, #qtrly.qtrlycomm as qtrlycommrep

 from #qtrly 
    inner join (
    select maxvalue = max(qtrlycomm), repnbr
    from #qtrly
    group by repnbr
    ) as m
    on #qtrly.repnbr = m.repnbr 
    and #qtrly.qtrlycomm = m.maxvalue;
```

order by `row_number`

```
  select top 1 with ties
        #qtrly.repnbr, #qtrly.qtrlycomm as qtrlycommrep

    from #qtrly 
        order by 
            row_number() over(partition by repnbr 
            order by qtrlycomm desc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one value per tax id.  You need to include that.  For instance:

```
select q.Repnbr, sum(q.QtrLYComm) as qtrlycommrep
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over(partition by repnbr, taxid order by QtrLYComm desc) as seqnum
      from #qtrly q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1
group by q.Repnbr;
```

However, I would be inclined to use two levels of aggregation:

```
select q.Repnbr, sum(q.QtrLYComm) as qtrlycommrep
from (select distinct repnbr, taxid, QtrLYComm
      from #qtrly q
     ) q
group by q.Repnbr;
```

Comment: I added the taxid in both of these queries and it takes me further away from what I need to get to.  To bad I can't sum by nested groups within SSRS.

Comment: @BIReportGuy . . . You are saying that these do not do what you want?  They should work on the sample data you provided.

Comment: Sorry, your code was perfect, but I was trying to do to much in my query.